# Getting an embed url for an already created docusign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

In docusign is it possible to create a signing request via the web interface and then retrieve the sigining URL via the API

at the moment, I update the Envelope using the API to attach a clientUserID as this is lacking when created via the web interface.

Then I retrieve the signing view url however, there is no signing tab when navigating to that url. The only action I have is to close.

I have tested using the API and the envelope contains signing tabs so I'm not sure what the issue would be.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post your JSON request for your api call and the sequence of API calls your are making. With the information you have given we cannot tell why the tabs are not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a DocuSign envelope if you assign one or more tabs to your recipient it becomes what's known as a **Free Form** signing experience, where the recipient decides where to sign the document.

On the other hand if you specify one or more tabs for the recipient then it's a **Guided Signing** experience.  In guided signing the recipient can only sign and take actions at the tabs the sender has specified.

It sounds like you are successfully creating the envelope and signing URL but that there are no tabs configured for the signer.  If that's the case you should confirm your code is identifying the recipient correctly by specifying the `name`, `email`, `recipientId`, and `clientUserId` values.

I would also check that the tabs are being set in your request body correctly for the given recipient.  First get the recipient information for the envelope using the [EnvelopeRecipients: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) API to ensure the data is what you expect, then generate the signing URL using the corresponding data.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that the there was an error whereby the clientUserId value I was setting was in fact empty. I debugged this using the EnvelopeRecipients: list method. It seems strange that it would generate a signing url without error under these conditions

Comment: Great, please accept the answer in that case since it was indeed a bad (or missing) clientUserId value that was causing the tabs not to get assigned.  Thanks.